# Dask to hdf5 write fails, "h5py cannot be pickled"

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, hdf5, h5py

Below is the part where it produces an error:

```
procDask = da.stack(procArrays)
print(procDask)
print(procDask.compute())    
    
#da.to_hdf5('out.hdf5',{'/arr',procDask})
    
f = h5py.File('out.hdf5',mode='w')
d = f.require_dataset('/a', shape=procDask.shape, dtype=procDask.dtype)
da.store(procDask, d)
```

my procDask shows to be a

```
dask.array<stack, shape=(3, 3, 3), dtype=int16, chunksize=(1, 3, 3), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```

However using any of the above-mentioned writing methods (both the commented and uncommented one), gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: h5py objects cannot be pickled
```

It is a little more verbose, showing source code etc, but I suppose this is the main error.
Am I using the methods wrong?

EDIT:
Here is a code that can reproduce the error

```py
def main():
    procArray = da.ones((3,3,3))
    procArray.to_hdf5('testout.hdf5','/arr')
    client.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client()
    main()
```

Comment: nobody pickles da stack .... nobody

Comment: Who or what is telling you that you can do this?

Comment: @hpaulj https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html this is the doc I was trying to follow, it shows both methods, but I think I am using it wrong, I'm not sure where though

Comment: Full traceback might help.  It's hard to say whether it's `dask` or `h5py` that's complaining.  There may be something too 'complex' about `procDask`, esp. its dtype.  In the `da.store` example, `x` is a numeric numpy array.

Comment: @hpaulj When using numpy arrays for the store function, i get the error "ValueError: All sources must be dask array objects"

Answer (score 1):

Correct, H5Py objects can not be pickled, and so can not be used within a distributed setting.  I recommend using the `to_hdf5` method to sidestep this.  It handles the tricks necessary to get things to work well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've added a code which reproduces the error on my machine, but uses the to_hdf5 method. Could you please take a look? It occurs when I initialize a client, but wouldn't not doing that be the same as serial code?

Comment: Hrm, interesting.  I went to go raise an issue and found this: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3074